# Android studio. Bundle returns only the last value from selected

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, bundle

I have a `listView` with custom adapter, where I have an `checkBox` and `TextView`, and when I select some CheckBoxes, I'm adding them into `bundle` and send into another `fragment`. In that fragment I have a simple TextView, where I need to get the value from `bundle` and show in that TextView. But the problem is, that when I'm getting the selected values from bundle and set in TextView, it shows only the last value. How can i solve this? Thank you.

Here the fragment where I'm adding the selected values into bundle.

```
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ArrayList<Profession> professionList = dataAdapter.getProfessionList();
            ArrayList<String> getProfessions = new ArrayList<>();
            personalInfoFragment = new PersonalInfoFragment();
            for (int i = 0; i < professionList.size(); i++) {
                Profession profession = professionList.get(i);
                if (profession.isSelected()) {
                    getProfessions.add(profession.getName());

                    Bundle setProfessions = new Bundle();
                    setProfessions.putStringArrayList("String", getProfessions);

                    personalInfoFragment.setArguments(setProfessions);
                }
            }
            replaceFragment();
        }
    });
```

Ok watch here. the `PersonalInfoFragment` is the fragment where i need to send the values. And the `replaceFragment` method replaces the fragment. I done debug and I'm adding the selected values into bundle successfully.
On `nextButton` click it saves the selected data into bundle and replaces the fragment.

Now here's the fragment where I need to get the bundle and show in textView.

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    if (bundle != null) {
        ArrayList<String> getProfessionName = bundle.getStringArrayList("String");
        if (getProfessionName != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < getProfessionName.size(); i++) {
                profession_text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                profession_text.setText(getProfessionName.get(i) + ",");
            }
        }
    }
```

ProfessionText is my textView where I need to set the values. But in that textView shows only the last item from bundle. How to fix this? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < professionList.size(); i++) {
    Profession profession = professionList.get(i);
    if (profession.isSelected()) {
        getProfessions.add(profession.getName());
       }
}
Bundle setProfessions = new Bundle();
setProfessions.putStringArrayList("String", getProfessions);
personalInfoFragment.setArguments(setProfessions);
replaceFragment();
```

And in next fragment,

```
profession_text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
profession_text.setText("");
if (getProfessionName != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < getProfessionName.size(); i++) {
        String txt = profession_text.getText().toString() + getProfessionName.get(i) + ", ";
        profession_text.setText(txt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what i can see..u need a list of values to be displayed right..what is happening here is on each iteration you set a new  value for professional text which overwrites the one that was there previously..thats why you are seeing the last value..i think if you want a list of textviews you have to create a new textview in the loop..which in this case you are better off using a listview or recycler view.